# Java Payroll ACME Project, Compiling problems

Tags: java, compilation

I have to create a program which has to include three or more classes including my Main class which will run the class simultaneously. Right now, I have a class called EmployeeRecord, which will create arrays for the employees information (employee full name, tax ID, employee ID, and their wage), and another class called Payroll, which is the class I am having the most trouble. In my if and else if statements, I am getting an error when trying to compile stating "incompatible types: double cannot be converted to java.util.ArrayList." I cannot quite understand or find a fix to solve the problem. I have posted my two classes for you. Thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * 
 * @Lab Three
 * @author Joseph Malachosky 
 * @version 9/14/2015
 */
public class Payroll
{
//ArrayLists that will use methods from EmployeeRecords.
ArrayList<String> employeeNames2;
ArrayList<Double> employeeWages2;

ArrayList<Integer> emID = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Double> hours = new ArrayList<Double>();
ArrayList<Double> totalPay = new ArrayList<Double>();
//Creating the hours and wages variables.
private double hoursWorked = 0.0;
private double hoursWorked2 = 0.0;
private int weeks = 0;
private String employeeID = "%03d";
private int quit = 1000;
private int i = 0;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public void setEmployeePayroll()
{
    // Constructs a new EmployeeRecord.
    EmployeeRecord e = new EmployeeRecord();
    e.setEmployeeInfo();

    employeeNames2 = e.getEmployeeNamesArrayList();
    employeeWages2 = e.getWageArrayList();

    // Local variables used in setEmployeePayroll.
    double totalPay2 = 0.0;
    double totalHours = 0.0;
    double overTime = 0.0;
    double overTime2 = 0.0;

    System.out.println("Please enter ACME employee ID, the week they worked (1 or 2), and the number of hours worked. This information should be entered in the order the names were entered. Enter 0 when you are done inputing information.");

    while(quit != 0)
    {
        quit = input.nextInt();
        if(quit == 0)
        {
            break;
        }

        weeks = input.nextInt();

        if(weeks == 1)
        {
            hoursWorked = input.nextDouble();
        }
        else if(weeks == 2)
        {
            hoursWorked2 = input.nextDouble();
        }

        /*
         * I am checking to see if the employee is going to be paid for overtime and also calculating the pay for both weeks.
         * 1) My first if statement indicates whether or not the employee worked over 40 in week one and week two.
         * 2) My first else if statement indicates whether the employee works more than 40 hours in week two but not week one.
         * 3) My second else if statement indicates whether the employee works more than 40 hours in week one but not in week two.
         * 3) My third else if statement finally indicates that the employee worked over 40 hours in both week one and two.
         */
        if(hoursWorked > 0 && hoursWorked <= 40 && hoursWorked2 > 0 && hoursWorked2 <= 40)
        {
            totalHours = hoursWorked + hoursWorked2;
            hours.add(totalHours);
            totalPay = totalHours * (employeeWages2.get(i - 1));
            totalPay.add(totalPay2);
            hoursWorked = 0.0;
            hoursWorked2 = 0.0;
        }
        else if(hoursWorked2 > 40 && hoursWorked > 0 && hoursWorked <= 40)
        {
            overTime2 = hoursWorked2 - 40;
            totalHours = hoursWorked + hoursWorked2;
            hours.add(totalHours);
            totalPay = totalHours * (employeeWages.get(i - 1)) + (overTime2 * 1.5);
            tPay.add(totalPay);
            hoursWorked = 0.0;
            hoursWorked2 = 0.0;
        }
        else if(hoursWorked > 40 && hoursWorked2 <= 40 && hoursWorked2 > 0)
        {
            overTime = hoursWorked - 40;
            totalHours = hoursWorked + hoursWorked2;
            hours.add(totalHours);
            totalPay = totalHours * (employeeWages.get(i - 1)) + (overTime * 1.5);
            tPay.add(totalPay);
            hoursWorked = 0.0;
            hoursWorked2 = 0.0;
        }
        else if(hoursWorked > 40 && hoursWorked2 > 40)
        {
            overTime = hoursWorked - 40;
            overTime2 = hoursWorked2 - 40;
            totalHours = hoursWorked + hoursWorked2;
            hours.add(totalHours);
            totalPay = totalHours * (employeeWages.get(i - 1)) + (1.5 * (overTime + overTime2));
            tPay.add(totalPay);
            hoursWorked = 0.0;
            hoursWorked2 = 0.0;
        }

        i = terminate;
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Employee Number  |  Employee Name    |  Hours Worked  |  Total Pay");
    for(int i = 1; i <= e.getEmployeeNamesArrayList().size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(String.format(employeeID, i) + "              | " + emID.get(i - 1) + "        | " + hours.get(i - 1) + "           | " + totalPay.get(i - 1));
    }
}
```

}

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
/**
 * Creating the objects and getMethods for each item that is stored in EmployeeRecord.
 * @Lab Three
 * @author Joseph Malachosky 
 * @version 9/14/2015
 */
public class EmployeeRecord
 {
/*
 * Creating the array and instance variables for EmployeeRecord consisting
 * of TaxID numbers, Employee Names, Wages, Employee ID numbers and hours worked.
 */
ArrayList<String> employeeNames = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> taxIDList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Double> employeeWages = new ArrayList<Double>();

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

private String employeeID = "%03d";
private String employeeFullName = " ";
private String taxID = " ";
private double wage = 0.0;
//Adding employees.
public void setEmployeeInfo()
{
    System.out.println("Please enter the full names of each ACME employee, their employee tax ID, and their employee wage rate. Press Q when you are done entering employee information.");

    while(employeeFullName != "Q")
    {
            employeeFullName = input.next();
            if(employeeFullName == "Q")
            {
            break;
            }
            taxID = input.next();
            wage = input.nextDouble();

            employeeNames.add(employeeFullName);
            taxIDList.add(taxID);
            employeeWages.add(wage);

            System.out.println("Employee ID  |  Employee Name        |  Tax ID          |  Wage");
            for(int i = 1; i <= employeeNames.size(); i++)
            {
                System.out.printf(String.format(employeeID, i) + "          | " + employeeNames.get(i - 1) + "              | " + taxIDList.get(i - 1) + "          | " + "%1.2f",employeeWages.get(i - 1));
                System.out.println();
            }
    }
}

/**
 * Creating a method that returns the employee ArrayList employeeName.
 */
public ArrayList<String> getEmployeeNamesArrayList()
{
    return employeeNames;
}

/**
 * Creating a method that returns the employee's Tax ID ArrayList taxIDList.
 */
public ArrayList<String> getTaxIdsArrayList()
{
    return taxIDList;
}

/**
 * Creating a method that returns the wages ArrayList 
 */
public ArrayList<Double> getWageArrayList()
{
    return employeeWages;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
 ArrayList<Double> totalPay = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

and then:

```
 totalPay = totalHours * (employeeWages2.get(i - 1));
```

Does your compiler not tell you the line number?

Answer (score 0):

i've found your mistake.

change:

totalPay = totalHours * (employeeWages2.get(i - 1));

to:

totalPay2 = totalHours * (employeeWages2.get(i - 1));

Comment: btw bro, there are still many errors in your program, but mostly are just typing/spelling errors...nothing major, just go through your program carefully and i think you'll be fine..

Comment: I did get the program to compile and I have made a Main method to run the payroll class but now it is saying that I am going out of bounds of the array.